# Where can I find hi-res stock photography previews?

Tags: resource-recommendations, stock-images

Does anyone know of a stock photo resource that offers high-res watermarked comp(preview) images?

Creating mock-ups with the tiny comps that getty provides really dials back the look of the mockups.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

RM agencies, Getty Images for example, have "Comping File License" which is free of charge or for a minimal fee.

I know only two RF agencies that provide comp images which are [Dreamstime](http://www.dreamstime.com/) and [123rf](http://www.123rf.com/), I'm sure there are more. Large images (with watermark) are available for registered users only.

Comment: I've downloaded the comps, but they seem to be very low-res, even if I'm logged in (at least on Getty) But I'll have to try the other ones you suggested.

Answer (score 0):

Dreamstime offer the largest watermarked thumbnails of any of the microstock sites I have come across. http://www.dreamstime.com/

Answer (score -1):

You can use free alternatives. There is a lot of quality ones coming to the fore. I suggest unsplash.com.

Of course, these such sites might not have the breadth and volume of imagery you need. These can be a brilliant alternative when you're looking for more atmospheric imagery. They are high quality and have no restrictions - you get the full, high res image immediately with no watermark and no need to provide attribution, even for commercial work.

Be sure to check sites like this if you're not looking for anything too specific.

Comment: To make this answer more useful, you should add some specifics, such as the quality of such a site as compared to established micro stock or big name stock houses. Keep in mind this is a professional designer looking for the answer to a fairly specific question.

Answer (score -1):

Hit <kbd>Ctrl/Command</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>4</kbd> and select comp image on the stock photo site. Depending on how large you need it, this was large enough for a pdf comp/proof for my client.

Comment: For which stock photo sites is that key combo? It does not do anything for me.